# populating jQuery List from JSON array while one element of the JSON Array false

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I am getting back this JSON object from an Ajax call it will be larger than one object but starting with just one record for now.

```
[{
 "SCENARIOID":"b9711a68-fb67-4b5c-bf79-a8a7a9a27df3",
 "USERID":"35be8bbb-99dc-44bc-9d84-9bcc937d79d6",
 "DateConfirmed":"\/Date(1434603186197)\/",
 "IsCorrect":true
}]
```

I have a `<div id=test> </div>` in my code and I am wanting to populate an unordered list with the `USERID` from the JSON object but only when `IsCorrect == true`

My current try is

```
$('#test').append('<ul id="fullCorrectByList"><ul/>');
$.each(response, function (key, data) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function (index, data) {
        if (index == 'IsCorrect' && data == true) {
            console.log('IsCorrect and True');
            //how do I console.log USERID for this json record?
        }
        console.log(index + ' : ' + data)
    })
})
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of the second loop, if the properties you want to deal with are constant.

```
$('#test').append('<ul id="fullCorrectByList"><ul/>');
$.each(response, function (index, record) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(record);
    if (record.IsCorrect) {
        console.log('correct', record.USERID)
    }
})
console.log(response);
```

---

If you want to make your code work, then just rename the variables uniquely to access the closure values

```js
var response = [{
  "SCENARIOID": "b9711a68-fb67-4b5c-bf79-a8a7a9a27df3",
  "USERID": "35be8bbb-99dc-44bc-9d84-9bcc937d79d6",
  "DateConfirmed": "\/Date(1434603186197)\/",
  "IsCorrect": true
}];

$('#test').append('<ul id="fullCorrectByList"><ul/>');
$.each(response, function(index, record) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(record);
  $.each(record, function(key, value) {
    if (key == 'IsCorrect' && value == true) {
      console.log('IsCorrect and True');
      //how do I console.log USERID for this json record?
      console.log('USERID: '+record.USERID)
    }
    console.log(key + ' : ' + value)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks alot!  this worked.  Next step to append the li to ul with the record.USERID.